# get the first entry where value is not null SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with these 3 columns:

`value`
`date`
`id`

For each id i would like to determine the first value using date to order. Is this a valid approach?:

```
    ;with cte as
    (
        select 
            id
            ,date
            ,value
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date asc) AS RN 
        from Bla
where value is not null
    )
    select 
        * 
    from cte
    where RN = 1
```

Comment: Yes, but if value can be NULL then add a WHERE clause to exclude NULL values to the cte definition.

Comment: Why don't you try it to see if this is a valid approach or not.  We don't have the data.  You are the one with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to use `TOP 1 WITH TIES`, ordering the records like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES id, [date], [value]
FROM BLA
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN [value] IS NULL THEN '2525-12-31' ELSE [date] END)
```

Comment: thanks I guess this makes the use of a cte and then using RN = 1 redundant. Correct? If s much neater!

Comment: It's a shorter code, and at least IMHO more readable, and yes, when you do it like this you don't need the CTE. If you have many rows in the table it would be nice to know if there's a performance difference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is a valid approach. I would do it the same way, maybe without the asterisk and without the semicolon in the beginning (since I also don't use a full stop to begin a sentence):

```
WITH 
  cte (id, [date], [value], RN) AS (
    SELECT id, [date], [value],
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY [date])
    FROM Bla
    WHERE [value] IS NOT NULL
  )
SELECT id, [date], [value]
FROM cte
WHERE RN = 1;
```